# How to get an Autosys job to run at XX:XX UTC?

Tags: autosys

I am looking at a JIL with parameters `start_times` (currently, `01:00`) and `timezone` (currently, `Europe\London`). How do I make the job run at 1 am UTC? Is there a `timezone` code for it? Is `timezone` optional, and omitting it will make the time UTC?

Answer (score 1):

To follow up on Piyush's answer, the command to get available timezones is

autotimezone -l

When run on your autosys server box it will provide output like this

```
Entry                                             Type    Zone
----------------------------------------          ------  ----------------
AbuDhabi                                           City     Arabian-Z
Adelaide                                           City     Australia/Adelaide
Africa-Z                                           Zone     SAT-2
Africa/Cairo                                       Alias    Egypt
Africa/Cape_Verde                                  Zone     AAT1
Africa/Casablanca                                  Zone     WET+0,M3.5.0,M10.5.0/03:00:00
Africa/Harare                                      Alias    Africa-Z
Africa/Johannesburg                                Zone     SAS-2
Africa/Monrovia                                    Zone     WAT+0
```

You can then use either the Entry or Zone as your value for the timezone field in your jil

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

If the timezone attribute is not mentioned, the job would be scheduled as per the default time of the server in which Autosys Scheduler is setup intially.

Since, UTC and GMT doesnot have time difference, use:

```
start_times = 01:00    
timezone: GMT
```

This should work. There is a command to get the list of the timzezone codes which i dont have it handy now. i shall update on that soon.